# Shift each row of pandas dataframe independently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [11, 22],
        1: [0.001, 0.005],
        2: [0.004, 0.006],
    }).set_index('id')
```

and another df that specifies the left shift we need to make for each id

```
s_df = pd.DataFrame({
                'id': [11, 22],
                'shift_val': [0, 1],
            }).set_index('id')
```

I want to left shift the ids 1 and 2 by the corresponding shift_val

```
        out = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': [11, 22],
            1: [0.001, 0.006],
            2: [0.004, np.nan],
        }).set_index('id')
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`shift` doesn't support multiple periods, so you have to loop.

You can use:

```
df1.apply(lambda s: s.shift(-s_df['shift_val'].get(s.name, 0)), axis=1)
```

Or, with `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1.loc[x].shift(-s_df['shift_val'].get(x, 0))
           for x in df1.index], axis=1).T
```

Output:

```
         1      2
uid              
11   0.001  0.004
22   0.006    NaN
```